# How to solve GeoService errors for MapKit when adding map overlay

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, mapkit, overlay

I've made a viewController that is showing a third party map as an overlay to the standard apple map(MapKit). This did work earlier, but now I'm getting some errors that I don't understand. I hope you are able to help.

Seems like there is some issue with a database file...

```
2017-11-09 00:10:04.397439+0100 Shoota[13022:4546380] [GEODBWriter] /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/GeoServices/GeoServices-                 1357.31.9.8.2/GEODBWriter.mm:601 Could not open database (/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.geod/MapTiles/MapTiles.sqlitedb): (14) unable to open database file
2017-11-09 00:10:04.398077+0100 Shoota[13022:4546380] [GEODBWriter] /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/GeoServices/GeoServices-1357.31.9.8.2/GEODBWriter.mm:601 Could not open database (/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.geod/MapTiles/MapTiles.sqlitedb): (14) unable to open database file

2017-11-09 00:10:04.412848+0100 Shoota[13022:4546380] [logging] API called with NULL prepared statement
2017-11-09 00:10:04.413219+0100 Shoota[13022:4546380] [logging] misuse at line 84067 of [2b0954060f]
2017-11-09 00:10:04.413228+0100 Shoota[13022:4546380] [logging] API called with NULL prepared statement
2017-11-09 00:10:04.413232+0100 Shoota[13022:4546380] [logging] misuse at line 84067 of [2b0954060f]

2017-11-09 00:10:04.413256+0100 Shoota[13022:4546380] [GEODBWriter] /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/GeoServices/GeoServices-1357.31.9.8.2/GEODBWriter.mm:437 SQL error: (21) out of memory

2017-11-09 00:10:04.435568+0100 Shoota[13022:4546267] [VKDefault] Tile 34210.17884.16 (128) in current unloaded state for 0.01 seconds - Raster Overlays Above Labels - Failed to decode (terminal) (0.01 sec)
2017-11-09 00:10:04.435602+0100 Shoota[13022:4546267] [VKDefault] Tile 34208.17884.16 (128) in current unloaded state for 0.01 seconds - Raster Overlays Above Labels - Failed to decode (terminal) (0.01 sec)
```

The code below is the UIViewController that I use.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class recordVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
var tileRenderer: MKTileOverlayRenderer!


// set initial location in Aspøya
let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 63.011018, longitude: 7.914721)

// Set the zoom level of the location
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,                                                                  regionRadius, regionRadius)


    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)


}


func setupTileRenderer() {


    let template =  "https://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_gmaps?layers=norgeskart_bakgrunn&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}&format=image/jpeg"

    let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: template)

    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true

    mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)

    tileRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: overlay)

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // hide the tab bar


    // Runs the function to get overlay tiles when page is reloaded
    setupTileRenderer()

    // Sets the map settings
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.showsCompass = true
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated: true)
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
    mapView.isRotateEnabled = true


    // Center the map on a defined location
    centerMapOnLocation(location: initialLocation)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    return tileRenderer
}
```

}

Comment: Have I broken the link to the database? Or is it just the upgrade to Xcode 9 and swift 4 that has caused some issues?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?